# add a character to a list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of items, say `x = ['Zwi', 'sche', 'n', 'ab', 'schlus', 'ses']`
I am trying to write a loop to add hyphen between one word at a time and the result should be something like below:

```
Zwi-schenabschlusses
Zwische-nabschlusses
Zwischen-abschlusses
Zwischenab-schlusses
Zwischenabschlus-ses
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Post the code that you've written so far.  What output does it produce?  Does it give an error?

Answer (score 3):

you can do

```
x = ['Zwi', 'sche', 'n', 'ab', 'schlus', 'ses']

s = "".join(x)
# Zwischenabschlusses

y = []
cumlen = 0
for i in x[:-1]:
    cumlen += len(i) 
    y.append(s[:cumlen]+"-"+s[cumlen:])

print(y)
```

Output:

```
['Zwi-schenabschlusses', 'Zwische-nabschlusses', 'Zwischen-abschlusses', 'Zwischenab-schlusses', 'Zwischenabschlus-ses']
```

Answer (score 2):

Just stuffing the hyphen into any place...

```
for i in range(1, len(x)):
    print(''.join(x[:i] + ['-'] + x[i:]))
```

Comment: This is IMO the best solution. The main trick is to identify what the problem actually is.

Answer (score 1):

Below code should work:

```
x = ['Zwi', 'sche', 'n', 'ab', 'schlus', 'ses']
modifiedX = []
for i in range(len(x) - 1):
    newString = ""
    for j in range(len(x)):
        if j == i + 1:
            newString += "-"
        newString += x[j]
    modifiedX.append(newString)
print(modifiedX)
```

**Output:**

```
['Zwi-schenabschlusses', 'Zwische-nabschlusses', 'Zwischen-abschlusses', 'Zwischenab-schlusses', 'Zwischenabschlus-ses']
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner in Python using [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it):

```
x = ['Zwi', 'sche', 'n', 'ab', 'schlus', 'ses']
print([("".join(x[0:i]) + "-" + "".join(x[i:])) for i in range(1,len(x))])
```

Output:

```
['Zwi-schenabschlusses', 'Zwische-nabschlusses', 'Zwischen-abschlusses', 'Zwischenab-schlusses', 'Zwischenabschlus-ses']
```

Comment: you can omit 0 from your first slice

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> x = ['Zwi', 'sche', 'n', 'ab', 'schlus', 'ses']
> d = [''.join(x[:range_]) + "-" +''.join(x[range_:]) for range_ in range(1, len(x))]
> ```

outputs:

```
['Zwi-schenabschlusses',
 'Zwische-nabschlusses',
 'Zwischen-abschlusses',
 'Zwischenab-schlusses',
 'Zwischenabschlus-ses']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use list comprehension with f-strings:

```
print(*[f"{''.join(x[:i])}-{''.join(x[i:])}"  for i in range(1, len(x))], sep='\n')
```

**output:**

```
Zwi-schenabschlusses
Zwische-nabschlusses
Zwischen-abschlusses
Zwischenab-schlusses
Zwischenabschlus-ses
```

or you can use a generator with `join` method:

```
def generate_str(x):
    add_word = ''
    for word_index, word in enumerate(x[:-1]):
        add_word += word
        yield f"{add_word}-{''.join(x[word_index + 1:])}"

print('\n'.join(generate_str(x)))
```

**output:**

```
Zwi-schenabschlusses
Zwische-nabschlusses
Zwischen-abschlusses
Zwischenab-schlusses
Zwischenabschlus-ses
```

Answer (score 1):

```
strs = ['Zwi', 'sche', 'n', 'ab', 'schlus', 'ses'] 

for index in range(1,len(strs)):

    out = '{}-{}'.format(''.join(strs[0:index]),''.join(strs[index:])) 
    print(out)


Zwi-schenabschlusses
Zwische-nabschlusses
Zwischen-abschlusses
Zwischenab-schlusses
Zwischenabschlus-ses
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ['Zwi', 'sche', 'n', 'ab', 'schlus', 'ses']
combinedStr = ''.join(x)
output = []
slicing_counter = 0
for index in range(len(x) - 1):
    len_substring = len(x[index])
    slicing_counter = slicing_counter + len_substring
    output.append(combinedStr[0:slicing_counter] + '-' + combinedStr[slicing_counter:])
print(output)
```